# Oauth2 service creation hasAccess() fails in Google Sheets script for all users except owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth-2.0

I'm using the https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2 library in a Google Sheet script to call an external API. It works well for the owner of the sheet. For all other users it fails in creating the service/property store? It fails the "Service.hasAccess()" condition.

I suspect I am missing some sort of permissions somewhere. I have given users Edit permissions on the Sheet and have gone through other various gyrations trying to figure this out. I decided to apply this script via a Standard Project.

Scope are applied explicitly in the manifest and all works swimmingly for the sheet owner.

''''''''Google Apps Script, Spreadsheet Script in GCP Standard Project

```
function authorizeUser() {

  var myService = getMyService();

  if (myService.hasAccess()) { 

  >FAILS THIS CONDITION for all except spreadsheet owner
  }

}

function getMyService() {

  return OAuth2.createService('sky')
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://oauth2../authorization')
  .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.../token')
  .setClientId('fee......')
  .setClientSecret('Ighh.....')
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
  //.setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
  // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

  .setParam('login_hint', Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())
}

>I believe the failure is occurring in OAuth2.gs here

 function createService(serviceName) {
   return new Service_(serviceName);
}
```

OAuth2.gs: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/dist

Any thoughts?

D M

Comment: Can we see your parameters and the API guide?

Comment: How are they calling the function ? form the Apps Script Editor? Or did you create an Add-On? Please share the [minimal code to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the post. It never gets far enough to make the API call.

Comment: I believe the failure is occuring in Oauth2.gs here

Comment: >I believe the failure is occurring in OAuth2.gs here

     function createService(serviceName) {
       return new Service_(serviceName);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the suggested code to validate the service state in the apps-script-oauth2 library is not indicative of whether or not the Oauth process can be completed.

> 2. Direct the user to the authorization URL
>    Apps Script UI's are not allowed to redirect the user's window to a new URL, so you'll >need to present the authorization URL as a link for the user to click. The URL is >generated by the service, using the function getAuthorizationUrl().

```
function showSidebar() {
  var driveService = getDriveService();
  if (!driveService.hasAccess()) {
```

I was able to complete my Oauth process regardless of the state returned by has.Access() . I'm not sure if this is a time sensitive operation or something else is at play. At any rate I was able to proceed and develop a final solution as a GAS web app.